# Calling a JSON file based on user input from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have a countries.json file which contains country and regional information. I am getting users to select country via a Python generated dropdown list from the countries.json file. This works and the country is selected. But because python works in the backend, I can not call the second phase, "state" unless the user first submits the form.

So instead I can call the country that has been chosen in JavaScript just with:

```
document.getElementById("country").addEventListener("change", function() {
    let country_chosen = document.getElementById("country").value; 
  });
```

And this works. So, the user has input the country, and based on the change, the name of the country is now in the console.

A single entry in the JSON file might look like this (this is just the first one):

```
{
    "code2": "AF",
    "code3": "AFG",
    "name": "Afghanistan",
    "capital": "Kabul",
    "region": "Asia",
    "subregion": "Southern Asia",
    "states": [
      {
        "code": "BDS",
        "name": "Badakhshān",
        "subdivision": null
      },
```

For this example, if the user picks Afghanistan from the dropdown generated by Python then they could also then pick a state based on all the states in Afghanistan etc.

The input selection is based on Jinja templating:

```
<select name="country" id="country" ref="country">
{% for country in countries %}
{% if profile.country == country.name %}
    <option value="{{ country.name }}" selected>{{ country.name }}</option>
{% else %}
    <option value="{{ country.name }}">{{ country.name }}</option>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

So, I want to repeat a similar input, except driven by JS from the frontend.

So I'll have a select name="state" so Python can read the input on submit, but everything else in this part needs to be driven by JS. So, a for loop will call all the states in that country.

But this, unfortunately, is where I have never done this before. I have never used JS to call a JSON file, let alone a JSON file I have produced (well, copied) myself and have it stored at the site. So, where do I start? I have the name of the selected country, now how do I call the JSON file to populate the state input dropdown?

Thanks for helping me in the right direction with this one.

I am trying this in jQuery, but I am getting nothing, not an error, nothing:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'countries.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    $.each(data['states'], function(index, value){
      console.log(index);
      console.log(value['name']);
      console.log(country_chosen);
    })
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), ES6:

```
fetch('my/url') // Call the fetch function passing the url of the API as a parameter
.then(function(data) {
    // Your code for handling the data you get from the API
})
.catch(function() {
    // This is where you run code if the server returns any errors
});
```

With [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), Vanilla JS:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  } else {
    // We reached our target server, but it returned an error

  }
};

request.onerror = function() {
  // There was a connection error of some sort
};

request.send();
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried something in jQuery but I get nothing. I note that you are using a URL - does that mean I have to go via a URL (say, my GitHub repo) to access the file and I can not do it locally?

Comment: You can test it "locally", but you'll always need to run your web page from a web server, due to browser security restrictions.